# Where can I share my js SharePoint library without getting my post deleted?

Tags: support, deleted-questions

Seems unfair, I've been building a js libraray for SharePoint requests on apps and I just wanted to share it with SP developers. My post was deleted a few minutes upon creation with no comments or explain whatsoever. Any mod / admin able to explain how should I do it? Thnks

Answer (score 2):

You are free to ask any question you want, and then answer it yourself. But you are not free to post something that is not a question, this site is based around Q&A!

So what you need to do is;

- First write a question that is well formed and follows the [guidelines](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).
- Then, post an answer that states that you have created a js SharePoint library that is perfect for this type of problem, include the link and some basic usage that will solve your "figurative" question.

See, that way you will follow this sites Q&A format :)

Comment: So, asking for feedback is not a valid question. But putting a fake question and then asking for feedback will be just fine. And you really think this is productive? Thanks anyway, no need to reply, I am going to follow the quideline. Chears

Comment: I think the problem with that specific question was that the body of the question in no way showed that you wanted anything else than to spread your project. Sure, the title did ask a question, but the body of the question did not

Comment: ok, I just did post another question, hope this works. Here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/97656/is-there-a-js-library-for-rest-and-jsom-sharepoint-basic-tasks Just to get it right though, is there anything wrong with spreading my project since it's free an on site's subject?

Comment: Looks much better, I edited it a bit and upvoted ;)

Comment: thanks, Robert, sorry 4 the mess